# Droopy Avocado tree

Tags: trees, avocado

Have a four foot tall Avocado.  Stays inside with grow lights until temperature stays above 50F at night.  Never any problems.  This year, put it outside and it droops but, only when in the sun?  Not a water issue but, I did plant in a big dark brown pot.  Maybe sun is heating up the pot and making roots unhappy in the extra heat?

Comment: Read about this topic: "wilting point."  *A condition in which a plant begins to use water from its own tissues for transpiration because soil water has been exhausted.*  (Free Dictionary)  But it's a bit complicated.  I think if you dig a little bit deeper into that topic, the wilting in the sun will make more sense to you. / Maybe re-pot in a larger pot and think carefully about your growing medium.

Comment: I think aparente001 is on to something. Just because soil is wet/moist doesn't mean that the plant is able to get enough water from it to keep from wilting. Perhaps the plant grew a lot of leaf mass inside to take advantage of lower light levels without the need for supporting root mass. Then when moving outside in more intense light, the water demands of the new leaves exceed the ability of the roots to meet the demand. Also the leaves would have gotten "soft" inside over the winter, and would need to acclimatize before being able to adequately control moisture in full sun.